# Is it a good practice to wrap datatypes in custom classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, classes

So in my current application, I was thinking to make a extended class for all the datatypes. For `int`, it will be something like `ExtendedInt`, for `bool` it will be something like `ExtendedBool`.

These individual extended classes will expose some special functonality bound to that type. For example, this is how i think my `ExtendedInt` will look like:

```
public interface IExtended
{
   bool IsModified { get; set; }
}

Public class ExtendedInt: IExtended
{
   private bool m_IsModified;
   private int m_MaxValue = int.MaxValue ;
   private int m_MinValue = int.MinValue;
   private int m_Value=int.MinValue;
   private int m_MaxValue = int.MaxValue ;
   private int m_MinValue = int.MinValue;

   public bool IsModified
      {
    get { return m_IsModified; }
    set { m_IsModified = value; }
      }


    public int Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
        set
    {
    // Only change the value if it is different.

             if (m_Value != value)
       {
          // Only set the value if it is in the valid range, if any max/min exists.
          if ((m_MaxValue > -1) && (value > m_MaxValue))
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("Value is above maximum value permitted.");
           }
           else if ((m_MinValue > -1) && (value < m_MinValue))
           {
               throw new ArgumentException("Value is below minimum value permitted.");
           }
           else
           {
              m_Value = value;
              this.IsChanged = true;
              if (m_Parent != null) m_Parent.DirtyState();
            }
               }
           }
       }
```

Similarly, I will provide `ExtendedBool`, `ExtendedDouble`, `ExtendedDate`, `ExtendedString`, etc..

Is this considered the best practice or it is overhead for my application?

Comment: You do realize that basic types are *already* an abstraction, right?  Why complicate things unnecessarily?  What value do your abstractions provide and what potential problems could they possibly introduce?  Is the time you are spending on this actually adding value or is it simply giving you something to toy around with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too much overhead - [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) and [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) seem to give you what you need. The checking you do on your setters will never be executed because an int will never be less than `int.MinValue` or greater than `int.MaxValue` to begin with.

Only create wrappers over types where you're adding intrinsic business (or technical) value that your consumers will benefit from. I'm afraid the `ExtendedInt` example you provide doesn't seem to meet that criteria over `int? myInt;`

Comment: Agreed. You are absolutely right abt Extension methods and i think i shud use them if i need to give additional flexibility on my type. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

@Asdfg - Keep it simple!

As written, I would say this is not a best practice at all, and should be avoided. It will be a (small) performance drag and a (large) addition of non-useful complexity if your plan is sweeping - any `int` will instead be `ExtendedInt`.

[I say "small" performance drag since I don't think that will be a problem compared to the far larger penalty in the complexity you will be introducting. One example: will you be supporting all `int` primatives in `ExtendedInt` like +, /, %, ++, casting, bitmasks, and so forth? Other programmers working on your code will be confused. Very messy.]

On the other hand, there is nothing wrong with writing a class that encapsulates needed behavior - in fact, that is a big part of object oriented design. Just that you would only use it when you have a good reason.

In your particular example, my read of your code suggests perhaps you are attempting to create a `BoundedInt` abstraction rather than the (too) generic `ExtendedInt` which doesn't tell us anything about the intent of the class. What does "Extended" mean? Doesn't reveal much.

Your comment `// Only set the value if it is in the valid range, if any max/min exists.` further suggests you intend to allow objects of this class to have settable ranges (though these methods are not shown). As Jesse points out, as written, the defaults you give are not useful, but with customizable ranges this might be a useful class. A plausible use case would be for a data object to associate with a UI element for which only a given range of values is allowed (disallowing negative age values, or rental dates in the past, and so forth).

Similarly, the IsModified method suggests tracking data updates. Only useful if you have a scenario where knowing whether an int has changed value. And realize these are two separate concerns - dirty tracking & restricting its range.

Comment: But if he is aiming for that "range" idea, I would suggest a generic class `Range<T>` or something similar, maybe with readonly properties `T? MinValue` and `T? MaxValue`.

Comment: I agree @ANeves that would be a good idea for implementing such a class.